# Suddenly cannot start appium service programmatically

Tags: python, pytest, appium

I must be missing some dependencies I think because it was working before I wiped my computer clean.

The test suite starts appium service automatically like so:

```
appium_service = AppiumService()
appium_service.start(
        args=['--local-timezone', '--address', APPIUM_SERVICE_HOST, '-p', APPIUM_SERVICE_PORT])
```

It was working flawlessly before I had to wipe clean my computer. After reinstallation it gets stuck after starting a test:

```
pytest                                                     
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
```

and the only way out is to interrupt it with keyboard.

Appium service logs is full of messages like this (and nothing else until keyboard interruption):

```
2022-08-23 15:16:50:059 [Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on localhost:4723
2022-08-23 15:16:50:263 [HTTP] --> HEAD /status
2022-08-23 15:16:50:264 [HTTP] {}
2022-08-23 15:16:50:272 [HTTP] No route found for /status
2022-08-23 15:16:50:276 [HTTP] <-- HEAD /status 404 12 ms - 211
2022-08-23 15:16:50:277 [HTTP] 
2022-08-23 15:16:51:278 [HTTP] --> HEAD /status
2022-08-23 15:16:51:278 [HTTP] {}
2022-08-23 15:16:51:283 [HTTP] No route found for /status
2022-08-23 15:16:51:284 [HTTP] <-- HEAD /status 404 6 ms - 211
2022-08-23 15:16:51:284 [HTTP] 
2022-08-23 15:16:52:292 [HTTP] --> HEAD /status
```

Any ideas how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

you may need specify /wd/hub as your route path, like: appium --base-path /wd/hub